# where are doGet() and doPost() methods in the servlets translated from jsps

Tags: jsp, servlets

In the Servlets that are translated from jsps , I notice that there is `_jspservice()` method but no `doGet()` and `doPost()` methods ? how does the servlet differentiate the `GET` and the `POST` methods ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real difference in handling of `GET` and `POST` requests in JSP. If you are interested in what method was used, you can call [`getMethod()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getMethod%28%29) to find out.

The way JSPs work is the same as if you overrode [`service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#service%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) in a Servlet instead of `doGet` / `doPost`.